My icon shows up as [object Object] when I use jQuery
I am new to jQuery thats why I don't understand how the element I create through jQuery shows up as [object Object] on my website. The class of my <i> is from the toolkit Font Awesome, it will make it to an icon. Instead of displaying an icon, my website displays [object Object]. The purpose of my code is to make this icon to shake.
I've read other posts on stack overflow but it does not solve my problem. I have tried to create different elements than <i>, but that does not solve the issue.
let unlockIcon = $('<i>').addClass('fa-solid fa-unlock unlock lock');
let parent=clueBox.querySelector(".lockedClueContent")
                    
parent.append(unlockIcon);
                    
var times = 10;
var duration = 200;
for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
  unlockIcon.animate({
    left: (i % 2 === 0 ? "-" : "+") + "=50"
  }, duration);
}
alert(  JSON.stringify(unlockIcon)  );
unlockIcon.on("click", function() {
  unlockCluePopUp(clue.id);
});


Can you edit your question and turn the code into a runnable snippet (using the toolbar button in the editor)?

The issue is because you're mixing up plain JS and jQuery methods.
In your code you use document.querySelector() to retrieve .lockedClueContent. Therefore the parent variable holds a HTMLElement object, not a jQuery object. As such you're calling the native append() method, not the jQuery implementation. As you pass a jQuery object to this native method, it coerces it to a string and appends it - resulting in '[object Object]'.
To fix the problem, make sure you use the same framework for all DOM interactions, whether that's using jQuery:


const $clueBox = $('#cluebox');
const $unlockIcon = $('<i>').addClass('fa-solid fa-unlock unlock lock').text('foo');
const $parent = $(".lockedClueContent")

$parent.append($unlockIcon);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cluebox">
  <div class="lockedClueContent"></div>
</div>



Or native JS:


const clueBox = document.querySelector('#cluebox');
const parent = document.querySelector(".lockedClueContent")

const unlockIcon = document.createElement('i');
unlockIcon.classList.add(...['fa-solid', 'fa-unlock', 'unlock', 'lock']);
unlockIcon.textContent = 'foo';

parent.append(unlockIcon);
<div id="cluebox">
  <div class="lockedClueContent"></div>
</div>



